# install4j updater with silent version check display release notes

Tags: install4j

I'm using the Updater with silent version check in Unattended mode with a progress dialog that is configured to launch automatically with the launcher. It auto updates perfectly. I was wondering though, if it is possible to display a screen with some information about the new release (and/or a link to release notes) while still maintaining the silent unattended mode? I know I can do this in GUI mode, but I want to keep the updates automatic/unattended and mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

No, in unattended mode this is not possible. You could condense the GUI mode in such a way that you don't have so many screens and all the actions are executed together.